# Alternative way to show that the special orthogonal group is compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness, orthogonal-matrices

To show that the special orthogonal group ${\rm SO}(n,\mathbb R)$, carrying the subspace topology induced by ${\rm Mat}_{n}(\mathbb R) \cong {\mathbb R}^{n}$, is compact many proofs use the Heine-Borel theorem.

As an alternative proof, does it suffice to observe that the continuous, real-valued function $\det: {\rm SO}(n, \mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded on ${\rm SO}(n, \mathbb R) $ (because $\det(A) = 1$ for all $A \in {\rm SO}(n, \mathbb R)$) and to deduce that this is equivalent to compactness of ${\rm SO}(n, \mathbb R)$ (by another theorem)? If not, why?

Comment: The fact that the determinant function is bounded over a domain is not enough to deduce that the domain is compact.  For instance, the group $SL(n,\Bbb R)$ fails to be compact.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Let's say X is a metric space. There is a theorem that says a continuous real-valued function is bounded on X if and only if X is a compact topological space (carrying the topology induced by the metric). That's what I was trying to use. Since that doesn't work, I guess that means we can't look at SO(n) as a topological space induced by a metric, correct? If that's not the reason, then I still don't know why we can't use the theorem mentioned in this comment.

Comment: Your "theorem" is false.  It is not true that a metric space $X$ is compact if and only if *one* choice of continuous real-valued function on $X$ is bounded.  After all, $\mathbb R$ is a metric space in the usual way and the constant function $f(x) = 1$ on $\mathbb R$ is bounded. That does not mean $\mathbb R$ is compact.  Go back and carefully reread whatever source you were looking at. There is a theorem that *if* a metric space is compact then *all* continuous functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded.

Comment: @user1728 Looks like I was sloppy and missed one very important detail. Thank you for pointing this out. In that case my question has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For this to work you would need something like the determinant to be a [*proper map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map), that is a map such that the inverse image of every compact set is again compact.

Not every continuous map is proper, for example consider multiplication $ℝ × ℝ → ℝ$. The inverse image of $\{1\}$ is the hyperbola, which is unbounded and so certainly not proper.

As Omnomnomnom mentioned in the comments, the special linear group $\operatorname{SL}_n (ℝ)$ is an unbounded inverse image of $\{1\}$ under the determinant, so the determinant is not proper. In fact, the set
$$\Big\{\smash{\big[\begin{smallmatrix}x & 0\\ 0 & y\end{smallmatrix}}\big]; x, y ∈ ℝ,~xy = 1\Big\}$$ yields an embedded hyperbola in the special linear group.